# ein Dorf oder einem Dorf?

Tags: dative, nominative

> In Juhnde, **einem Dorf** in Niedersachsen.

warum steht hier ein Dorf im Dativ anstatt Nominativ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das liegt an der Präposition *in*. *in* verlangt entweder den Dativ oder den Akkusativ, je nachdem, ob es es sich um eine Orts- (Dativ) oder Richtungsangabe (Akkusativ) handelt.

*einem Dorf in Niedersachsen* ist hier eine [Apposition](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Apposition) zu dem Dativ-Objekt *Juhnde* und steht daher mit diesem in Kasus-Kongruenz. *Juhnde* steht hier wegen der Präposition im Dativ.